# Can integers of the form $4^m(8n+7)$ be expressed as a sum of three squares? Is there a proof by induction for this question?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that an integer of the form $4^m(8n+7)$ cannot be written as a sum of three squares.

Comment: What is the real question? The one from the title or the one from the body?

Comment: They're the same thing. I just meant to ask if there's a way to solve it using induction.

Comment: Your question was edited. When I wrote my comment, it had $4^m$ in the title and $4m$ in the body. Besides, why do you want an inductive proof? This is very easy using modular arithmetic.

Comment: Oh I see. I apologize. Yeah I realize there's a proof with modular arithmetic but the question asks for a proof using induction.

Comment: See my answer (which could do with a bit of polishing up to make a decent proof, but it gives you the rough idea). I don't think it's hard to find this proof online, but I'll give you the benefit of the doubt. It's also customary to indicate your attempts at a problem before you post it on here; something to keep in mind for future questions, as you're more likely to get help and responses.

Comment: @SamStreeter Got it, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, induct on $m$. Suppose $4^m\left(8n+7\right) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$. If $m = 0$, it should be fairly easy for you to verify that there are no solutions by looking at both sides modulo $8$ and listing all possible squares modulo $8$ (thinking about what the sum of any three of them could/couldn't be). Then assume $m \geq 1$. By looking at both sides modulo $4$ and since squares are either congruent to $0$ or $1$ modulo $4$, we conclude that all of $x^2$, $y^2$ and $z^2$ are congruent to $0$ modulo $4$, hence all of $x$, $y$ and $z$ are even, hence $4^{m-1}\left(8n+7\right) = \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{y}{2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^2$ is an expression of $4^{m-1}\left(8n+7\right)$ as the sum of three integer squares. This gives you your induction step.

Comment: Ok, so when you get 4^(m-1)*(8n+7) = (x/2)^2 + (y/2)^2 + (z/2)^2 and perform the inductive step on m. You say suppose ... for m and then prove that ... for m+1. However, m+1 simply gives you 4^(m)*(8n+7) which is a contradiction right?

Comment: Moreover, if I wanted to prove the case for m=1 then it would be 4*(8n+7) how would I go about doing that? If I try and expand it, I would get 32n+28 and that's congruent to 4 (mod 8). But a^2 +b^2 + c^2 is congruent to 4 (mod 8).